# linq to sql concatenate - FirstName and LastName for a ListBox

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get the following to work. I have a table with the Fields **FirstName**, **LastName** and **DoctorId**. I would like to populate a .net ListBox using Linq to SQL. Here's what I have found and borrowed:

In a class I've called DALClass:

```
public List<Doctor> GetListDoctorsNames()
{
  using (var db = new WaitListDataContext())
  {
    return (from c in db.Doctors
            select new
            {
              FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
              DoctorId = c.DoctorId
            }
            ).ToList<Doctor>;
  }
}
```

The error has to do with the ").ToList;" line. The error is:

> Error 1   Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. Did you intend to invoke
>   the
>   method?   Q:\myapp\WaitList\App_Code\DALClass.cs  37  16  Q:\myapp\WaitList\

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to put `<String>` instead of `<Doctor>`. I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `.ToList<Doctor>();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is returning an anonymous type, and you're not actually invoking the `ToList` method. You probably need to specify the data type select clause, and invoke `ToList` method using parentheses, like this:

```
return 
    (from c in db.Doctors
     select new Doctor
     {
        FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
        DoctorId = c.DoctorId
     })
    .ToList<Doctor>(); // or just .ToList();
```

---

**Update**

To address the second error ("*'Doctor' does not contain a definition for 'FullName'*") the problem is that you haven't defined any such property on your `Doctor`.

You could try to define a separate property on `Doctor`, but I'm not sure if Linq-to-SQL will allow that. You could also reuse one of the existing properties (e.g. `LastName`), but that doesn't sound particularly elegant.

I'd recommend designing a separate entity (usually you'd accomplish this with an anonymous type but since it appears you're returning this from a method, that's not an option if you care about type safety):

```
public class DisplayDoctor
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
}

return 
    (from c in db.Doctors
     select new DisplayDoctor
     {
        FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
        DoctorId = c.DoctorId
     })
    .ToList<DisplayDoctor>(); // or just .ToList();
```

Comment: This must be close. However, the error is, "'Doctor' does not contain a definition for 'FullName'".

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I did not have the property "FullName". Creating a class that to hold just the fullname and id is perfect. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The first problem, `ToList()` is a method and needs to be called as one:

```
).ToList<Doctor>();
```

Second, you won't be able to cast an anonymous type to a `Doctor` class.  What you want is:

```
  return (from c in db.Doctors
            select new Doctor() // Create Doctor instance
            {
              FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
              DoctorId = c.DoctorId
            }
          ).ToList(); // No longer a need to specify type on generic method
```

**Update:** If it were me, I'd just update the `Doctor` class (the auto-generated models are partial classes anyway) to have a `FullName` property like so:

```
public partial class Doctor
{
   public string FullName // Read only FullName property
   {
      get
      {
         return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
      }
   }
}
```

Then, you can just return your list of `Doctor` objects (I'm assuming `db.Doctors` is a collection of `Doctor` objects):

```
  return (from c in db.Doctors select c).ToList();
```

And bind directly to the `FullName` property of the object.

Comment: I don't have a property, "FullName". I just made the up to try and solve this problem. A Doctor doesn't have "FullName". Should I try something else to try and solve my original problem of populating a ListBox with the complete name of a doctor?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the `Doctor` class is actually an entity from the database context. In that case you need to create your own type and return that rather than `Doctor`.

```
public List<MyDoctor> GetListDoctorsNames()
{
  using (var db = new WaitListDataContext())
  {
      return db.Doctors.Select(c => new MyDoctor()
             {
                 FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                 DoctorId = c.DoctorId
             }).ToList();
  }
}

public class MyDoctor
{
  public string FullName {get; set;} 
  public int DoctorId {get; set;} //Or what ever type DoctorId is
}
```

Comment: You are correct! I needed a class to hold the property FullName as my Linq to SQL class didn't have one. Thank you so much. I learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're simply missing the parentheses indicating you  are trying to execute the ToList<>() method :)

```
using (var db = new WaitListDataContext())
{
  return (from c in db.Doctors
        select new
        {
          FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
          DoctorId = c.DoctorId
        }
      ).ToList<Doctor>();
```

}

Comment: It seems to be closer. Now the error reads, "Error 1 'Doctor' does not contain a definition for 'FullName'". Is the Select statement incorrect?